# How to have one card for one item in stead of getting all cards populated with the last item in database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have this fragment:

```
    public class AttractionsFragment extends Fragment {

        Context context;
        private View LocationView;
        private RecyclerView myLocationsRecycler;
        private DatabaseReference ModelRef;

        public AttractionsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            LocationView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);


            myLocationsRecycler = LocationView.findViewById(R.id.cat_recycler);
            myLocationsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
            ModelRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("attraction_list");


            return LocationView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                    .setQuery(ModelRef, Model.class)
                    .build();

            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ModelViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ModelViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ModelViewHolder holder,  int position, @NonNull Model model) {


                    ModelRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                String name = data.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                String image=data.child("image_link").getValue().toString();

                                holder.title.setText(name);
                                Picasso.get().load(image).into(holder.imageBg);


                     }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ModelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
                return new ModelViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        myLocationsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }


    public static class ModelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageBg;
        TextView title;

        public ModelViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            imageBg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }

    }

}
```

And this database

```
{
  "attraction_list": {
    "01":{
       "name": "Eye of London",
       "image_link": "gs://for-tourists-by-tourists.appspot.com/images/eye_london.png",
       "full_description": "As iconic for London as the Eiffel Tower is to Paris, the Coca-Cola London Eye is a spectacular testament to modern Britain. At 135 metres, the London Eye is one of the world's tallest observation wheels, providing up to 40 kilometres of panoramic views on a clear day. The gradual rotation in one of the 32 high-tech glass capsules takes approximately 30 minutes, offering breathtaking views of London and its famous landmarks. Whether it’s with family, friends or maybe a romantic Champagne Experience just for two, London Eye tickets are an integral part of any trip to London. See more of London for less with 365Tickets exclusive London Eye combination tickets."
    },
"02":{
   "name": "Tower Bridge",
   "image_link": "gs://for-tourists-by-tourists.appspot.com/images/tower_bridge.png",
   "full_description": "Completed in 1894 The Most Famous Bridge in the World is a marvel of Victorian engineering and the home of the Tower Bridge Exhibition. At 42 metres above the river Thames, a visit to the Tower Bridge exhibition boasts spectacular panoramic views of some of London’s most famous landmarks: The London Eye, Canary Wharf, and St Paul’s Cathedral can all be seen from its high-level walkways – and the budding photographers will love that the specially designed windows make capturing that iconic image an easy task. Visitors to the exhibition will discover the rich history of Tower Bridge with an ever changing variety of content throughout the year."
},
"03":{
   "name": "Buckingham Palace",
   "image_link": "gs://for-tourists-by-tourists.appspot.com/images/buckingham.png",
   "full_description": "Since 1837, Buckingham Palace has served as the official London residence of Britain's kings and queens. Today, we know it as the administrative headquarters of Her Majesty, Queen Elizabeth II."
},
"04":{
   "
```

name": "Big Ben",
   "image_link": "gs://for-tourists-by-tourists.appspot.com/images/big_ben.png",
   "full_description": "Although there is a charge for tours of the Houses of Parliament (aka Westminster Palace) during the summer recess, which are available to all, UK residents can do a tour ..."
}
}

And in my app all my cards get update with title "Big Ben" and that image, please help me to get in each card a different item.
The weird thing is that i have only 4 cards (as i should)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: that is the database structure: attraction_list is the first node, then position number and from that name, image_link, and full description. And i have two more sets like this each for a diffrent fragment and all of them are in a tabbed view.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the entire code: `ModelRef.addValueEventListener(/* ... */)` with `holder.title.setText(model.getName());`? Does it work this way?

Comment: Didn't work :( I have read it is about value event listener being a async task.  That because of that i can't populate a list to feed my card views. I anybody can help me get it wright please do so!